# Ошибка CS0103 Имя "Log" не существует в текущем контексте

Tags: c#

```
[Command("clear")]
[Summary("1000")]
[RequireBotPermission(ChannelPermission.AddReactions)]
public async Task NovoVoto([Remainder] string secondPart)
{
    Log.CMDLog(Context.User.Username, "Clear", Context.Guild.Name);

    if (secondPart.Length >= 200)
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Извините, но ваш голос не должен быть больше чем 200 слов");
        return;
    }

    var embed = new EmbedBuilder();
    embed.WithColor(new Color(126, 211, 33));
    embed.WithTitle("VOTE AQUI!");
    embed.WithDescription(secondPart);
    embed.WithFooter($"Голосование создано: {Context.User.Username}");

    RestUserMessage msg = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", embed: embed.Build());
    await msg.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("✅"));
    await msg.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("❌"));
}
```

Comment: В текущем пространстве имен (namespace) есть `Log`?

Comment: пространстве имен нету Log

Comment: откуда ты взял `Log`? где он объявлен и как?